# how to use imagemagick with tcpdf

Tags: php, imagemagick, tcpdf

I need to handle images in TCPDF

I get this error.. Imagemagick is installed, but how do I tell TCPDF the path to imagemagick?

```
TCPDF ERROR: TCPDF requires the Imagick or GD extension to handle PNG images with alpha channel.
```

Answer (score 19):

Just try by installing missing GD extension before you do anything else.

PHP 5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

PHP 7.1

```
sudo apt install php7.1-gd
```

PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt install php7.2-gd
```

PHP 7.3

```
sudo apt install php7.3-gd
```

And then Restart Apache/NGINX

```
#Apcahe
sudo service apache2 restart
#NGINX
service nginx restart
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php`<php version number >`-gd

Comment: For php 7.x you also need to specify the x version. For example `sudo apt install php7.1-gd`

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the GD or ImageMagick extensions for PHP (either one or the other will do). If you choose ImageMagick you need to make sure you have the packages installed.

Edit your php.ini file to enable the extension. On Windows:

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

or

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

On Unix/Linux:

```
extension=imagick.so
```

or make sure you have PHP compiled with the --with-gd option or install the php5-gd package. (For some distributions it may be called something like php54w-gd)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo yum install php56-gd
sudo service httpd restart
```

For CentOS folks.

Answer (score 2):

Im using Windows 10 with XAMMP 8.1.10.

Just **uncomment** (by removing the semicolon) the Line

```
;extension=gd
```

in your php.ini File (standard installation path: C:\xampp\php\php.ini).

In unchanged php.ini the number of the line is 920.

Comment: Even if your php.ini file does not contain that line, simply add it. It just works. No need to install GD libraries or download DLLs or anything.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP7.X on CentOS:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

Then restart your web server.

If a `gd.ini` file appears in the "Additional .ini files parsed" section of `phpinfo.php`, then it's successfully installed.

Comment: On cento OS 7.2, executing only `sudo yum install php-gd` worked for me.